# Git checkout -p HEAD regex search

Tags: regex, git

OK... doing a `git checkout -p HEAD` beings up the prompt ...

> Discard this hunk from index and worktree [y,n,q,a,d,/,j,J,g,e,?]?

Where `?` shows a help and `/` is...

> / - search for a hunk matching the given regex

So, I wanted to try it. I added a line in a file like `let mySillyString = "Hello, world"`.

If I do a git diff I can see several files and hunks that are in the worktree. (Including the `sillyString` one).

How would I use the `/` option to find my `sillyString` hunk.

When I enter `/` it gives the prompt

> search for regex?

I have tried several options but it still just offers up the hunk it is currently on.

What should I type in as my regex string to search for `sillyString` in a hunk?

**The git diff that I currently have**

I have anonymised it to remove stuff but it shows the important bits I want to try to achieve.

```
diff --git a/MyProject/AViewController.swift b/MyProject/AViewController.swift index 1b14a4522..3341eb355 100644
--- a/MyProject/AViewController.swift
+++ b/MyProject/AViewController.swift 

@@ -99,12 +99,6 @@ class AViewController: UIViewController, Str
         print("doing something here")
     }

-    func getImageURL() -> URL? {
-        print("doing something here")
-        print("doing something here")
-        return theImageURL
-    }
-
     func addPopGesture() {
         print("doing something here")

@@ -174,6 +168,12 @@ extension AViewController {

         stackView.addArrangedSubviews(views: someViews)
     }
+
+    private func getImageURL() -> URL? {
+        print("doing something here")
+        print("doing something here")
+        return theImageURL
+    }
 }

 extension AViewController { 

diff --git a/MyProject/AView.swift b/MyProject/AView.swift index b9e3349aa..962e255e2 100644
--- a/MyProject/AView.swift
+++ b/MyProject/AView.swift 

@@ -300,5 +300,7 @@ fileprivate extension UIImage {

         return someData
     }
+
+    let mySillyString = "Hello, world!"  
+
 }
```

From the diff you can see that I have moved some code in one file (there are additions and subtractions of the same code in that file). And then I have added my example hunk that I want to search for.

Comment: I have been looking into this and can't yet write up a full answer. To make a meaningful example, I think it will be helpful to have two hunks.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice ok... will add an example `git diff` that I have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short version:**

`/silly` should take you right to the hunk you want to add. It only searches for hunks inside the **same file** as the hunk you are currently located at.

**Long version:**

I don't have your file, so I used one of my own as an example. I added 3 comments so the diff looks like this:

```
diff --git a/Gemfile b/Gemfile
index 751838d..626c553 100644
--- a/Gemfile
+++ b/Gemfile
@@ -5,6 +5,8 @@ git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
   "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
 end

+# This is change 1
+
 # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
 gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.5'
 # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
@@ -18,6 +20,8 @@ gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
 # See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
 # gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

+# This is change 2
+
 gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
 # Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
 gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
@@ -39,6 +43,8 @@ group :development, :test do
   gem 'selenium-webdriver'
 end

+# This is a silly change
+
 group :development do
   # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
   gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
```

So now I checkout. It shows the first hunk, I search for "silly", it shows the 3rd hunk. I still have to answer if I want to add the hunk or not, this just makes it faster to move around a file with a lot of hunks.

```
$ git checkout -p HEAD
diff --git a/Gemfile b/Gemfile
index 751838d..626c553 100644
--- a/Gemfile
+++ b/Gemfile
@@ -5,6 +5,8 @@ git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
   "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
 end

+# This is change 1
+
 # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
 gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.5'
 # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
Discard this hunk from index and worktree [y,n,q,a,d,/,j,J,g,e,?]? /silly
@@ -39,6 +43,8 @@ group :development, :test do
   gem 'selenium-webdriver'
 end

+# This is a silly change
+
 group :development do
   # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
   gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
Discard this hunk from index and worktree [y,n,q,a,d,/,k,K,g,e,?]?
```

If you're getting the same hunk over and over again, it probably means your regex matches that hunk as well.

Comment: OK... I just had a realisation after looking at your answer. All your changes were in the same file. If i did a search for `/private` then it went to the hunk with the `private func...` Thanks (I feel like the docs are a bit misleading there, lol)